# Scala-reflect not found

Tags: scala, gradle

I have a Kotlin based Gradle project, where I'm using Scala. All my dependencies are coming from the internal repository, so I cannot use any Scala version, but only the ones available.
Because of that I have the following list of dependencies:

```
plugins {
  java
}
//...
apply(plugin = "scala")
//...
dependencies {
  implementation("org.scala-lang.scala-reflect:2.12.5")
  compileOnly("org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.9") {
    exclude("org.scala-lang.scala-reflect")
}
```

On paper it should work - I defined dependencies available on internal nexus.

However, when I try to build the project, I'm getting the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileScala'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':zinc'.
  > Could not find scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar (org.scala-lang.scala-reflect:2.10.10).
    > Searched in the following locations:
      <nexus_url>
```

Is it because of scala plugin?

---

**UPDATE**
I have checked that the error occurs, because the version of Zinc I have is  built on top of Scala 2.12.10. And since the version is not available on the nexus, it cannot be ran.
Is there a way to change the Scala version Zinc is using?

Comment: I guess that the exclude you added will have no effect since `scala-reflect` depeds on `scala-library` and not the other way around: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/build.sbt#L423 Why aren't you using the same version?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've removed the exclusion. However, the same error still occurs.

Comment: You didn't answer my other question. Why aren't you using the same version of Scala library and Scala reflect?

Comment: There is no version 2.10.10: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.scala-lang%20AND%20a:scala-reflect%20AND%20v:2.10.10

Comment: @cchantep I'm aware of that, but i have no idea, why zinc is trying to use that version.

Comment: @TomerShetah I got the code from the other developer.

Comment: @TomerShetah I did that with version 2.12.2 and and now the scala-reflect-2.12.10 is missing.

Comment: Try to figure out where is that 10 suffix comes from. I'd guess it is part of your gradle file.

Comment: @TomerShetah I have nothing like this in my gradle files.

Comment: Not sure it's that, but you spelt `implementation` wrong

Comment: @mfirry it's not that. In code it is correct.

Comment: Then please update your question with the current situation and current error.

Comment: @mfirry updated. Is there a way to change the Scala version Zinc is using?

Comment: have a look https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html#sec:configure_zinc_compiler

Comment: @mfirry yes, changing the Zinc version fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

After searching through Gradle Scala plugin documentation (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html#sec:configure_zinc_compiler)
I have found the solution.
What I had to do was changing the Zinc version:

```
scala {
  zincVersion.set("1.3.1")
}
```